# Variadic template, get function arguments value

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

My problem is the following:
I have a class declared as such:

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class API
{
    ReturnType operator()(Args... args)
    {
       // Get argument 0
       // Get argument 1
    }
};
```

I am in need of getting the arguments on by one, and so far the only way I've come up to (but I can not get it to work) is using `std::get`, as such:

```
std::get<0>(args);
```

Of course, this leads to a lot of errors.
I am new to variadic templates (and to C++11 at all) so I am quite lost at this point.

How could I get those arguments one by one?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get... one by one"?

Comment: I mean getting them as such:
`DWORD arg0 = "args[0]"`, `DWORD arg1 = args[1]`, etc

I mean, foreach arg passed to the function, accessing its values

Comment: Try a `std::tuple<Args>`, but for your application I'm somewhat lost to the point. You probably want runtime-indexing, not static (0,1,2). Dunno. you know your needs better than I.

Comment: What do you want to do with those arguments?

Comment: It's quite hard to explain, I'm going to push its values, something like `foreach argument: (code)=0x68, (code+1)=value`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capture the args in a temporary tuple ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85f0352d24984976)):

```
ReturnType operator()(Args... args)
{
   static_assert(sizeof...(args) >= 3, "Uh-oh, too few args.");
   // Capture args in a tuple
   auto&& t = std::forward_as_tuple(args...);
   // Get argument 0
   std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << '\n';
   // Get argument 1
   std::cout << std::get<1>(t) << '\n';
   // Get argument 2
   std::cout << std::get<2>(t) << '\n';
}
```

`std::forward_as_tuple` uses perfect forwarding to capture references to the `args`, so there should be no copying.

Comment: +1 for [`std::forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple), but can I ask why the `auto&&` instead of plain `auto`? Compiler will optimize away the move construct anyway, right?

Comment: @Snps Yes, in all likelihood the return move/copy from `forward_as_tuple` will be elided. I'm probably being unnecessarily paranoid with my use of `auto&&`. An entire `tuple` filled with rvalue references is like kryptonite, I feel like I should handle it with tongs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename ReturnType>
class API {
public:
    template<typename Arg>
    ReturnType operator()(Arg&& arg) {
        // do something with arg
        return (ReturnType) arg;
    }

    template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
     ReturnType operator()(Head&& head, Tail&&... tail) {
        // do something with return values
        auto temp = operator()(std::forward<Head>(head));
        return temp + operator()(std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    API<int> api;
    auto foo = api(1, 2l, 2.0f);
    std::cout << foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually found @WhozCraig suggestion to work. Simply setting up a tupple as `std::tuple<Args...> targs(args...);` and then using `std::get<i>(targs);`. Thanks anyways, it helps me understand variadic functions better.

Answer (score 0):

A few helper templates can do that for you. I'm not aware of one in stl that does it directly, but I like to roll my own templates anyways:

```
namespace Internal {
template <size_t Pos, typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct Unpacker {
    static auto unpack(Arg&&, Args&&... args) {
        return Unpacker<Pos - 1, Args...>::unpack(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct Unpacker<0, Arg, Args...> {
    static auto unpack(Arg&& arg, Args&&...) { return std::forward<Arg>(arg); }
};
} // Internal
template <size_t Pos, typename... Args>
auto unpack(Args&&... args) {
    return Internal::Unpacker<Pos, Args...>::unpack(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
auto unpacked0 = unpack<0>(1, "orange", 3.3f, "pie");
auto unpacked1 = unpack<1>(1, "orange", 3.3f, "pie");
auto unpacked2 = unpack<2>(1, "orange", 3.3f, "pie");
auto unpacked3 = unpack<3>(1, "orange", 3.3f, "pie");
// Will not compile, because there are only 4 arguments
// auto unpacked4 = unpack<4>(1, "orange", 3.3f, "pie");
fmt::print("{} {} {} {}\n", unpacked0, unpacked1, unpacked2, unpacked3);
```

Or in your case:

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class API {
    ReturnType operator()(Args&&... args) {
       // Get argument 0
       auto& arg0 = unpack<0>(args...);
       // Get argument 1
       auto& arg1 = unpack<1>(args...);
    }
};
```